# Javascript - Problema con función tipo autocompletar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente función

```js
$(function(){
  function normalizeWord(word) {
    var letters = [{
        search: 'áäàãâ',
        replace: 'a'
      }, {
        search: 'éëèê',
        replace: 'e'
      }, {
        search: 'íïìî',
        replace: 'i'
      }, {
       search: 'óöòõô',
       replace: 'o'
      }, {
        search: 'úüùû',
        replace: 'u'
      }, {
        search: 'ñ',
        replace: 'n'
      }, {
        search: 'ç',
        replace: 'c'
      }],
      normal;
    
    // Convertimos la palabra a minusculas
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    normal = word;

    // Por cada "letra"
    $.each(letters, function(idx, letter) {
      var re = new RegExp('[' + letter.search + ']', 'g');
      // Reemplazamos el caracter acentuado
      normal = normal.replace(re, letter.replace);
    });
  
    // Devolvemos un objeto con la palabra original y la normalizada
    return {
      original: word,
      normal: normal
    };
  }
  
  function normalizeWords(words) {
    var response = [];
  
    // Por cada palabra
    $.each(words, function(idx, word) {
      // Obtenemos la palabra normlalizada
      response.push(normalizeWord(word));
    });
  
    return response;
  }
  
  function sortNormalizedWords(a, b) {
    if (a.normal > b.normal) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.normal < b.normal) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
  
  function sortShortWords(a, b) {
    if (a.length > b.length) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.length < b.length) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
  
  //

   var palabras = ["anatomia","Ana","angie","anatómico","anatómica","análisis","analogía","analizar","anabólico","Analuz", "tu", "tú", "túnel"],
       // Obtenemos la palabras normalizadas (sin caracteres acentuados)
       words = normalizeWords(palabras);
  
  // Ordenamos el arreglo de la A a la Z
  words.sort(sortNormalizedWords);
  
  $( "#entrada").on('input', function() {
    var key = this.value,
        posibles = [],
        lucky = false;
    
    // Normalizamos el valor ingresado
    key = normalizeWord(key);
    
    // Por cada palabra
    $.each(words, function(idx, word) {
      // Validamos que contenga el valor ingresado
      if (word.normal.indexOf(key.normal) !== -1) {
        posibles.push(word.original);
        
        // Si es exactamente la palabra buscada
        if (key.original === word.original) {
          lucky = word.original;
        }
        // Si es igual a la palabras normalizada
        else if (!lucky && key.normal === word.normal) {
          lucky = word.nomral;
        }
      }
    });
    
    // Imprimimos todas las palabras que contienen el valor ingresado
    $('#posibles').val(posibles.join(','));
    
    // Si no encontramos la pablabra exacta, 
    // ordenamos el arreglo de posibles
    // y devolvemos la primera
    if (!lucky) {
      lucky = posibles.sort(sortShortWords)[0];
     }
    $('#acertada').val(lucky);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Entrada:
<input type="text" id="entrada"><br>
Posibles:
<input type="text" id="posibles" readonly><br>
Mas acertada:
<input type="text" id="acertada" readonly><br>
```

Mi problema es la escritura con mayúsculas **iniciales** o la **palabra entera**.

Es decir que si escribo en **Entrada** => **Tu**, El resultado(sugerencia) será **tu**. Notese la inicial.

Lo que quiero es que devuelva **Tu** de igual modo, pensé en que la palabra **Tu** (Notese la inicial) debería estar en el **Array() de palabras** pero eso hace muy inestable la función en sentido de que para algunas palabras devuelve la inicial en mayúscula y para otras no sin importar cómo las escriba (minúsculas o mayúsculas).

Para resumir, lo que quiero es que si escribo **Pa** devuelva **Pa** y si escribo **pa** devuelva **pa** :)

Cómo puedo resolver el problema?

Comment: Por cierto, en la linea `else if (!lucky && key.normal === word.normal) {
          lucky = word.nomral;
        }` es correcto ese `"nomral"`?

Comment: @Máxima: con ES6, `function eliminarDiacriticos(texto) { return texto.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g,""); }` (te ahorrarías unas... muchas líneas de código)

Comment: @Mariano pero entonces como sería el codigo completo junto con tu función? Porque intenté acomodarlo pero se me **descontroló** todo

Comment: @MáximaAlekz no estoy respondiendo a tu pregunta, sólo te estoy dando un consejo de cómo acortar una parte de tu código (que no es la del problema), si acaso te interesa

Comment: @Mariano, vale. Está bien :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambiando esta linea haces que si introduces un texto en mayúscula la primera letra, el valor de `#acertada` también.

```
// Si no encontramos la pablabra exacta, 
// ordenamos el arreglo de posibles
// y devolvemos la primera
if (!lucky) {
  lucky = posibles.sort(sortShortWords)[0];
 }
$('#acertada').val(lucky); // -> cambiar
```

Por esto:

> ```
> $('#acertada').val($('#entrada').val()[0]+lucky.substring(1).toLowerCase());
> ```

Coge la primera letra y la pone en mayúscula, y el resto la deja en minúscula.

```js
$(function(){
  function normalizeWord(word) {
    var letters = [{
        search: 'áäàãâ',
        replace: 'a'
      }, {
        search: 'éëèê',
        replace: 'e'
      }, {
        search: 'íïìî',
        replace: 'i'
      }, {
       search: 'óöòõô',
       replace: 'o'
      }, {
        search: 'úüùû',
        replace: 'u'
      }, {
        search: 'ñ',
        replace: 'n'
      }, {
        search: 'ç',
        replace: 'c'
      }],
      normal;
    
    // Convertimos la palabra a minusculas
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    normal = word;

    // Por cada "letra"
    $.each(letters, function(idx, letter) {
      var re = new RegExp('[' + letter.search + ']', 'g');
      // Reemplazamos el caracter acentuado
      normal = normal.replace(re, letter.replace);
    });
  
    // Devolvemos un objeto con la palabra original y la normalizada
    return {
      original: word,
      normal: normal
    };
  }
  
  function normalizeWords(words) {
    var response = [];
  
    // Por cada palabra
    $.each(words, function(idx, word) {
      // Obtenemos la palabra normlalizada
      response.push(normalizeWord(word));
    });
  
    return response;
  }
  
  function sortNormalizedWords(a, b) {
    if (a.normal > b.normal) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.normal < b.normal) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
  
  function sortShortWords(a, b) {
    if (a.length > b.length) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.length < b.length) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
  
  //

   var palabras = ["anatomia","Ana","angie","anatómico","anatómica","análisis","analogía","analizar","anabólico","Analuz", "tu", "tú", "túnel"],
       // Obtenemos la palabras normalizadas (sin caracteres acentuados)
       words = normalizeWords(palabras);
  
  // Ordenamos el arreglo de la A a la Z
  words.sort(sortNormalizedWords);
  
  $( "#entrada").on('input', function() {
    var key = this.value,
        posibles = [],
        lucky = false;
    
    // Normalizamos el valor ingresado
    key = normalizeWord(key);
    
    // Por cada palabra
    $.each(words, function(idx, word) {
      // Validamos que contenga el valor ingresado
      if (word.normal.indexOf(key.normal) !== -1) {
        posibles.push(word.original);
        
        // Si es exactamente la palabra buscada
        if (key.original === word.original) {
          lucky = word.original;
        }
        // Si es igual a la palabras normalizada
        else if (!lucky && key.normal === word.normal) {
          lucky = word.nomral;
        }
      }
    });
    
    // Imprimimos todas las palabras que contienen el valor ingresado
    $('#posibles').val(posibles.join(','));
    
    // Si no encontramos la pablabra exacta, 
    // ordenamos el arreglo de posibles
    // y devolvemos la primera
    if (!lucky) {
      lucky = posibles.sort(sortShortWords)[0];
     }
     
    $('#acertada').val($('#entrada').val()[0]+lucky.substring(1).toLowerCase());

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Entrada:
<input type="text" id="entrada"><br>
Posibles:
<input type="text" id="posibles" readonly><br>
Mas acertada:
<input type="text" id="acertada" readonly><br>
```

Comment: Y si escribo **tu** devuelve **tu** o **Tu**?

Comment: He añadido para que pruebes. Devuelve **Tu**. Necesitas que si lo introducido es en minuscula, que salga en minuscula?

Comment: Que sea **dependiente** de la forma en la que se escribe, pero que sólo aplique para la primera letra de la palabra. Es decir que si escribo **anabolico** devuelve **anabólico**, si escribo **Anabolico** devuelve **Anabólico**

Comment: ok, ahora estoy editandolo. un sec ^^

Comment: @MáximaAlekz perdona la espera, estuve liado. ya lo tienes funcionando como quieres